# Amazon Connect not waiting for customer input in Get Customer Input widget

Tags: amazon-lex, amazon-connect, call-flow

I've created a flow in Amazon Connect where an incoming call comes into a Get Customer Input widget. The widget plays an intro audio file and is connected to an existing Amazon Lex instance. Instead of waiting for the customer to say something, it immediately goes to the fallback flow. I can see from Cloudwatch that the intents are not being assessed by Amazon Lex as there's an error in the GetUserInput module, but I've also read that the timeout is 3 seconds in Connect - but the flow isn't waiting even one second. Can anyone help?

I've tried adding attributes such as the following in the Get Customer Input widget, to no avail.

x-amz-lex:audio:start-timeout-ms:[intentName]:[slotToElicit]
x-amz-lex:audio:end-timeout-ms:[intentName]:[slotToElicit]

To see if they'll update the timeouts to 5 seconds for both, but it's the same. No impact.

***Update*** I have been using the new Amazon Lex V2 menu system, but switched to the old 'classic' V1 version and created a bot...and it works with Amazon Connect. Any ideas?

***Another Update***
My AWS account is based in Europe (London) region, for info. As it turns out, after hours of testing different configuration, it seems that my selection of English(GB) as a language is the reason for the failures. When I added English(US), all of a sudden, the Intents started getting recognised. I also created a Lex version with just English(US), and it also works. All of this on the V2 version of Lex - as I said above, V1 seems to work fine out-of-the-box.

If anyone can suggest another reason, please do. However, I do feel it was the language settings, aka a bug!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you forgot to set the language attribute. If you use a Lex V2 bot, the **Language Attribute** defined in the contact flow has to match the language of your bot.

The best way to do this is to use the **Set Voice** block in your contact flow (even if it's a chat and not a voice contact).

You can also read about this in the documentation:
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/amazon-lex-integration-failures

Hope this helps!